# Retrieve the amount of bytes stored in the "write" end of a Linux anonymous PIPE

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pipe

My objective is to be able to determine how many bytes have been transferred into the write end of a pipe. Perhaps, one would need to access the `f_pos` member of the `struct file` structure from linux/fs.h associated with this pipe.

[struct file snipfrom fs.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEmdV.png)

Is it possible to access this value from a userspace program? Again, I'd just like to be able to determine (perhaps based on the f_pos value) how many bytes are stored in the kernel buffer backing the pipe.

I have a feeling this isn't possible and one has to keep reading until `read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)` returns less bytes than count.. then at this point, all bytes have been "emptied out" I assume..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we want to have each question post described a **single problem**. But your post is about several problems at once: 1. `What structure is defined that keeps track of the buffer` - this is part of the **kernel**. 2. `There must be some kind of structure pointed to be the index referred to by a file descriptor` - kernel keeps mapping from file descriptors for **all files**, not only for *pipes*. 3. Bytes available in the pipe can be requested by `ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &nbytes);`. Please, [edit] the question post and leave single question/problem in it.

Comment: Hello, this answered all my questions. I didn't actually notice you answered  them until reading your comment more carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amount of bytes available for read from the pipe can be requested by

```
ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &nbytes);
```

Here `fd` is a file descriptor, and variable `nbytes`, where result will be stored, is `int` variable.

Taken from: [man 7 pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html).

---

Amount of bytes available for **write** is a [different story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624071/pipe-buffer-size-is-4k-or-64k).